# How to call function with unlimited parameters

Tags: javascript, cpanel

Following cPanel UAPI function [store_filter](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/DD/UAPI+Functions+-+Email%3A%3Astore_filter) I need to call function with a iterated params if there is more than one rule or action, like:

- action1
- action2
- action3
- dest1
- dest2
- dest3
  and so on.

But I don't really understand how can I pass this iterate params to a function.

UPD

```
    $cpanel = new CPANEL(); // Connect to cPanel - only do this once.

// Create a new filter for user@example.com.
$new_filter = $cpanel->uapi(
    'Email', 'store_filter',
    array(
        'filtername'      => 'coffee',
        'account'         => 'user@example.com',
        'action1'         => 'deliver',
        'dest1'           => 'cheesecloth@example.com',
        'part1'           => '$header_subject:',
        'match1'          => 'contains',
        'val1'            => 'curds',
        'opt1'            => 'or',
        'part2'           => '$message_body',
        'match2'          => 'is',
        'val2'            => 'whey',
         )
);
```

Comment: Please look for functions with variable number of arguments.

Comment: can you show some meaningful code that illustrates your problem? at the moment you're using the word `iterate` and there doesn't seem to be anything iterable in the question

Comment: What about using arrays?

Comment: Does anybody ready the link in the body? To get successful response I need to send some iterable parameters. Please take a look at first message, I`ll update it with a PHP code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO you don't have to do anything extra. JavaScript comes equipped with [`Arguments object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), `arguments` is an reserved keyword which you can use like this:

```js
function unlimitedArgs() {
  console.log(arguments)
}

unlimitedArgs(2,4, 'v1');

unlimitedArgs(2,4, 'v1', [2,4,5], "some other value");
```

Or, you can use [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to do something like this perhaps:

```js
function unlimitedArgs(...gatherer) {
  console.log(gatherer)
}

unlimitedArgs(2,4, 'v1');

unlimitedArgs(2,4, 'v1', [2,4,5], "some other value");
```

NOTE: If you use spread operator the container variable (ie `gatherer`) will be of type `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

may be this example helps

```
function printNames(...names) {
  console.log(`number of arguments: ${names.length}`);
  for (var name of names) {
    console.log(name);
  }
}

printNames('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
```

Whatever may be the arguments you can pass unlimited arguments and access the same with the function like above.